# Remotely shutting down X on Solaris?

Tags: solaris

We have a Gnome session running on our remote server.  How can we ssh into the machine and shutdown X-Windows without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, are you trying to just shutdown X because of a locked application and restart it, or do you just want to stop X from running entirely?

Assuming you want to just kill X because of a locked-up application:
(examples below are from my OpenSolaris-based server, probably not applicable to Sol8 or 9)

```
bill@aperture:~# kill -9 2478
bill@aperture:~# ps ac | grep Xorg
2593 vt/2     S  0:00 Xorg
bill@aperture:~# kill -9 2593
bill@aperture:~# ps ac | grep Xorg
No immediate results, wait a few seconds to run check again
bill@aperture:~# ps ac | grep Xorg
2631 vt/2     S  0:00 Xorg
```

Notice that in this case, X restarted.   While this may be good if you're just trying to restart X after a lockup, sometimes you just want to shut GDM off entirely.  Check svcs for an entry for GDM.

> ```
>  bill@aperture:~# svcs | grep gdm
> online          9:10:05
> svc:/application/graphical-login/gdm:default
> ```

Well, look, I've got an entry for GDM.   Thanks to the wonders of SMF, no matter how hard I try, I can't kill X.   It keeps coming back from the dead.   Let's tell GDM to die-- no, let's just disable it via svcadm.

```
bill@aperture:~# ps acx | grep gdm
  2701 ?        S  0:00 gdm-binary
  2702 ?        S  0:00 gdm-binary
  2727 ?        S  0:01 gdmgreeter
bill@aperture:~# ps acx | grep Xorg
  2703 vt/2     S  0:00 Xorg
bill@aperture:~# svcadm disable gdm
bill@aperture:~# ps acx | grep gdm
bill@aperture:~# ps acx | grep Xorg
bill@aperture:~#
```

As a further note, I found [this mailing list thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/solarisx86/message/23397) helpful once upon a time, to fix the inability to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Bksp</kbd> to kill X on Solaris.   Basically, add a few lines to the configuration file for X.org to reenable handling of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Bksp</kbd> on certain Solaris installs.

Comment: I want to stop it because I don't want it running on the server.  Killing the X-server doesn't seem like the nice way to kill it.  I'll try this out tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I hope it helps out.    the svcadm disable thing *might* be what you need.  I hope....